# Ruler of the Seas, how to do it?

Tags: civilization-5, achievements

How do I sink a million ships? Well, not a million, 357 for the achievement?

What is a good setup? I set up a huge archipelago game with epic game length and raging barbarians... but ships still aren't spawning very fast, and I imagine it'll probably take 3-4 run-throughs to get the achievement.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Using the actual achievement name in the title is much better for the visibility of questions, so I took the liberty of changing the title.

Comment: @Oak: +1. Thanks, I meant to edit it in, but steam was still loading...

Comment: do the embarked units count towards this number?

Comment: Embarked units do NOT count towards this : http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33019/civilization-5-elizabeth-specific-achievement-domain/46347#46347

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, I think achievements such as those were designed to only be achievable through multiple playthroughs.

In any case, I think the idea to abuse barbarians in an archipelago map is good, just make sure that:

1. You get the honor social policy so that you're always aware where encampments are.
2. You don't destroy the encampments - leave them alive, and "camp" them by placing a ship nearby and destroying anything that spawns immediately.
3. Play with few opponents, if you can - barbarians only spawn (relatively) far from claimed territory, so you want as much of the map as possible to remain clear.
4. It's good that you play with slower pacing - it means there are more turns in which you already have powerful hunting units than when starting many new games.