# Civilization 5 Elizabeth-specific achievement domain?

Tags: civilization-5, achievements

The achievement specifically tied to Elizabeth (that's the English) is as follows:

Ruler of the Seas
As Elizabeth, sink and destroy 357 enemy naval units, across any number of playthroughs.

So my question is: do embarked land units count as naval units towards this total?

Comment: I think it does, because I got it and I don't remember sinking many actual ships. I just can't prove it.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/11291/8366, including the part about counting land units.

Comment: @DaveDuPlantis mm, not quite sure I see this as a duplicate. One's asking for tips on how you earn the achievement, the other's asking for how the game tracks the achievement progress.

Comment: @Mana, I'm not sure that it's possible to write a good answer for this question that doesn't overlap with the existing one; wouldn't the answer to this question (asked as a comment on the linked Q) fit better as an aside on Oak's answer, such as "Don't forget, embarked land units (do/do not) count as naval units toward this total"?

Comment: @DaveDuPlantis: Overlaps are okay. Just don't want duplicates. The other question is linked now; that will do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After having a look at both rules and source code, I can conclude that embarked units are NOT considered naval units.

> When a land unit is embarked it is unable to attack and unable to
>   defend itself against any attacks. Any naval unit can destroy an
>   embarked unit and will not even lose its remaining moves while doing
>   so. Cities and ranged units can also easily destroy embarked land
>   units by bombing them. In effect, embarked land units are considered
>   to be non-military units.

Also, wonders and abilities given to naval units will not be applied to embarked units, and I have killed well over 350 embarked units with Elizabeth (love doing that) without getting this achievement.

Comment: Civ 5 source code is finally available?

Comment: No, not really, but it's available to certain groups (ie. game designers)